# Display Input value from an array object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am bit new to react, I am trying to collect user data in a form as below and displaying in a grid table. When I select a particular row to edit, I am trying to show the same form again and data to be filled/displayed in respective Input control. But I am not sure how to display the Input control from an array object.

```
const inputs = [
    {
        id:"Title",
        type:"text",
        lable: "Title",
        placeholder:"Enter Title",
    },
    {
        id:"FirstName",
        type:"text",
        lable: "First name",
        placeholder:"Enter first Name",
    },
    {
        id:"LastName",
        type:"text",
        lable: "Last Name",
        placeholder:"Enter last Name",
    },
    {
        id:"Email",
        type:"email",
        lable: "Email id",
        placeholder:"Email id",
    },
];

//code for the form used to collect data and the same used to display again for edit

                      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

                            
                            {inputs.map((input) =>(
                            <div className="forminput" key={input.id}>   
                                <label>{input.lable}</label>
                                <input 
                                    name={input.id}
                                    type={input.type}
                                    placeholder={input.placeholder}
                                    onChange={handleInput}/>
                            </div> )
                            )}
                            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                            <button onClick={handleCancel}>Cancel</button>
                        </form>

//From grid control I have an array 'editData' which has the following data
{
    "id": "any5MNUZY5Z0ZMTrGwiXFj8gLpc2",
    "FirstName": "John",
    "LastName": "A",
    "Email": "abc@test.com",
    "Title": "MR",
    "timeStamp": {
        "seconds": 1682634222,
        "nanoseconds": 998000000
    }
}
I want to display this editData back in the form to display for user to edit. Please suggest.
```

Adding my full code here. It include a solution posted here. I still have the problem and the data is not showing in the form.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import SideBar from "../components/Sidebar";
import "../styles/Newuser.scss";
import Headerbar from "./Headerbar";
import image from "../img/no-image-icon-23494.png"
import UploadFileIcon from '@mui/icons-material/UploadFile';
import { doc, serverTimestamp, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { collection, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import {db} from "../../firebase";
import { auth, dbStorage } from "../../firebase";
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";
import { KeyboardDoubleArrowDownOutlined } from "@mui/icons-material";


const NewUser = ({inputs, title}) =>{
    const [userImage, setUserImage] = useState("");
    const [uploadedImgUrl, setUploadedImgUrl] = useState("");
    const [percentage, setPercentage] = useState(null);

    console.log (userImage);
    const location = useLocation();
    let editObject = location.state.editObject;

    //const [inputData, SetInputData] = useState({ })
    const [inputData, SetInputData] = useState(editObject)

    console.log("Edit Object", editObject)

    useEffect( () => {
        const uploadFile = ()=>{

            const name = new Date().getTime() + userImage.name;
            const storageRef = ref(dbStorage, name);
            console.log("file name", name);

            const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, userImage);

             


            uploadTask.on('state_changed', 
            (snapshot) => {
                // Observe state change events such as progress, pause, and resume
                // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
                const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
                console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
                setPercentage(progress);
                switch (snapshot.state) {
                case 'paused':
                    console.log('Upload is paused');
                    break;
                case 'running':
                    console.log('Upload is running');
                    break;
                 default:
                    break;

                }
            }, 
            (error) => {
                // Handle unsuccessful uploads
            }, 
            () => {
                // Handle successful uploads on complete
                // For instance, get the download URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...
                getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
                console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
                setUploadedImgUrl(downloadURL);
                SetInputData((prev) => (
                    {...prev, imgage:downloadURL
                    })
                
                );
                console.log("Input data: ", inputData);
            });

        }); 
    };
    
    userImage && uploadFile();
    }, [userImage]);


    useEffect(() => {
        SetInputData(editObject);
        console.log("Input data in effect: ", inputData);
    }, [editObject]
    )
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleInput = (e) => {
        const id = e.target.name;
        const val = e.target.value;
        SetInputData({...inputData, [id] : val});
        console.log(inputData);
    }

    const handleSubmit = async(e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();

      // Add a new document with a generated id.
      try{
            const res = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, inputData.Email, inputData.Password)
            // Add a new document in collection "users"
            await setDoc(doc(db, "users", res.user.uid), {...inputData,
                timeStamp: serverTimestamp(),
            });
            console.log("Document written with ID ");
            navigate(-1);
            
        }
      catch(err){
        console.log(err);
      }
      
        
    }

    const handleCancel = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        navigate(-1)
    }

    return(
        <div className="user">
            <SideBar />
            <div className="userwrapper" >
                <Headerbar />
                <div className="top">
                    <h1>New User Details</h1>
                </div>
                <div className="bottom">
                    <div className="left">
                    <img src = {
                        userImage ? URL.createObjectURL(userImage) : image
                        }
                        alt="" />
                        
                    </div>
                    <div className="right">
                        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                            <div className="forminput">
                                <label htmlFor="fileid">
                                    Select file : <UploadFileIcon className="icon"/>

                                </label>
                                <input type="file"
                                    id="fileid"
                                    onChange={(e)=>setUserImage(e.target.files[0])}
                                    style={{display : "none"}} />
                            </div>
                            
                            {inputs.map((input) =>(
                            <div className="forminput" key={input.id}>   
                                <label>{input.lable}</label>
                                <input 
                                    name={input.id}
                                    type={input.type}
                                    //placeholder={input.placeholder}
                                    defaultValue={inputData[input.id]}
                                    onChange={handleInput}/>
                            </div> )
                            )}
                            <button disabled={percentage !== null && percentage < 100} type="submit">Submit</button>
                            <button onClick={handleCancel}>Cancel</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>            
            </div>
        </div>
    )
};

export default NewUser;
```

Comment: I think, your issue is that you need a form control inputs that takes user data am I right?

Comment: Yes, not a new form preferably the existing form where I need to display the input values.

Comment: Hi, You can check my answer, I think it helps you.?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve your issue, you need to set `values` for all `inputs` in the array and then set `defaultValue` to read it instead of `value` cause, it will be [uncontrolled](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/input#im-getting-an-error-a-component-is-changing-an-uncontrolled-input-to-be-controlled). After then use `useState` to control those values. You could do like this:

```
import { useState } from "react";

//... inputs array
const handleSubmit = () => {};
const handleCancel = () => {};

const Form = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  return (
    <form>
      {inputs.map((input) => (
        <div className="forminput" key={input.id}>
          <label htmlFor="input">{input.lable}</label>
          <input
            name={input.id}
            type={input.type}
            id="input"
            defaultValue={input.value}
            // placeholder={input.placeholder} 
            onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
      ))}
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      <button onClick={handleCancel}>Cancel</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

Here is the live demo:

[image: Edit elastic-maxwell-9kby7d]

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This looks fine, but one problem is I can't set the value in the array as it will be dynamic. The input array is only to generate the form, the actual value will be in another array 'editData', so I may not be able to use this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You've got this form in React and it's set up to take new user data. But now, you want to use the same form to edit existing data. The data is coming from an 'editData' array.

First, let's add a `defaultValue` attribute to your input fields. This `defaultValue` will set the initial value of the input field when the form is rendered. It's perfect for what we're trying to do because it lets us set the initial value to the current value from 'editData'.

Here's a tweaked version of your code that should do the trick:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const inputs = [
    // your inputs here
];

const Form = ({ editData }) => {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState(editData);

    const handleInput = (e) => {
        setFormData({
            ...formData,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
    };

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(formData);
    };

    const handleCancel = () => {
        // your cancel logic here
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        setFormData(editData);
    }, [editData]);

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            {inputs.map((input) => (
                <div className="form-input" key={input.id}>
                    <label>{input.label}</label>
                    <input 
                        name={input.id}
                        type={input.type}
                        placeholder={input.placeholder}
                        defaultValue={formData[input.id]}
                        onChange={handleInput}
                    />
                </div>
            ))}
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            <button onClick={handleCancel}>Cancel</button>
        </form>
    );
};

export default Form;
```

In this code, we're doing a few things:

1. We're setting up a state variable `formData` to keep track of the form data. It's initially set to `editData`, which is the data you want to edit.
2. We've got a `handleInput` function that updates `formData` whenever an input field changes.
3. We've got a `useEffect` hook that updates `formData` whenever `editData` changes. This means that if `editData` changes, your form will update to show the new data.
4. Finally, we're setting the `defaultValue` of each input field to the current value of the corresponding field in `editData`. So when the form is rendered, each field will show the current value from `editData`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Exactly this is the solution I was looking for and I tried the same but I was unable to show the data back in form input controls even though console outputs show the correct value in useEffect.

Comment: @user1306926 What do you mean exactly by "form input controls"?

Comment: I mean the Input fields in the form. As per your point 4, defaultValue should in the fields, but its not showing. I have included my full component code in the original post for reference.